# how to store a text file into an array and count how many words are in it

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I was given a homework in which I need to count the number of words in a file and output how many words are the same. Like "a" in the whole text maybe it was repeated 350 times. I hope you get my point.

Now, im trying to do some tests and created a file("test.txt") containing:

```
Im a good boy
Hello World
A happy world it is
```

What I'm trying to do is storing it into an array to be able to count the words in the file. But I'm having a hard time. This is what i got so far.

```
void readFile() {
    System.out.println("Gi navnet til filen: ");
    String filNavn = sc.next();

    File k = new File(filNavn);
    try {
        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(k);
        while (sc2.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = sc2.nextLine();
            String[] m = line.split(" ");
            String x = m[0];

            System.out.println(x);
        }  
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.print("mmm");
    }
}
```

but this only outputs the first words on the line.

What I would like to see is the same as the text file. But stored in an array. How can I do it?

```
Im a good boy
Hello World
A happy world it is
```

Comment: Please untag JavaScript, as this is Java only, not dealing with JavaScript they are completely different languages. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java

Answer (score 1):

This will only print out the first word because of this

```
String[] m = line.split(" ");
String x = m[0];
System.out.println(x);
```

Here you are only assigning the first word in the array (created by your split) to the variable x and then printing only that word.

To print all the words you will need to loop the array like so

```
for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
{
     System.out.println(m[i]);
}
```

And to print the same as the file you could use `System.out.print()`. Note you will need to put the spaces back in and also account for the new lines. Below is one approach:

```
for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
{
     if(i == m.length - 1)
         System.out.print(m[i] + "\n");
     else
         System.out.print(m[i] + " ");
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Im getting the whole file now. But the result is that the output is downwards.

Comment: Yes, see the last note I've added

Comment: thank you very much. i didnt get it too clearly though, but it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since your post didn't say you HAD to do it in Java (although I am guessing that is the case), I offer this:

```
perl -e 'while(<STDIN>) { map { $w->{lc($_)}++; } split("\\s", $_); } map { print "$_ $w->{$_}\n"; } keys %{$w} ;' < test.txt
```